# Why would my Docker volume not work as expected?

Tags: docker, node-sass

I have a working docker image and am using docker-compose with these volumes:

```
volumes:
 - .:/usr/src/node-app
 - /usr/src/node-app/node_modules/node-sass/
```

The first line is set so I can modify code locally that appears in the running container. The second line is supposed to make sure that `node-sass` is excluded. This seems to be working fine on a few other projects, but not what I'm working on now and I can't find the difference.

My `Dockerfile` does a `COPY . .` on start followed by `npm install`, but `.dockerignore` has `node_modules*` within it and the container runs fine immediately after rebuild.

After some time, it fails because my machines node-sass folder ends up on the running container, so it has a Mac binary instead of the required Linux one. At first I thought it was happening when I ran `npm install`, but I just did an install with an arbitrary new package, updated a JS file, saw my server restart, and things still worked. I have no idea why the binary would get overwritten at a later point in time, but it keeps happening every hour or so.

Comment: Are you deleting the anonymous volume between tests to verify whether the file is in the volume or your image?

Comment: i’m not sure what that means, but i’m definitely not deleting anything. Are you implying the next time it happens I should startup without the volumes at all to see whats in the container?

Comment: Creating the volume without a name results in an anonymous volume, represented by a long guid that you'd see in `docker volume ls`. If compose reuses a previous anonymous volume, you wouldn't see changes you've made to your image in that directory, instead you'd see the prior state persisted in the volume. Running without a volume would also show you the image contents.